# redirecting a page from asp to aspx

Tags: asp.net

I was assigned a project I'm having some difficulty finding a solution or guide to, we have a asp shopping cart that currently runs in a classic asp page, we want to redirect once they click "checkout" to redirect to our newer aspx page.

any help is greatly appreciated.

edit: 
I have tried to simply do a redirect to the website giving it the information that it needs like order id, date, etc. however this method gives me an error with the web.config on the asp side. involving our target framework 4.5.2.

I am extremely new to web programming and this is my first non fix bug x issue.

Comment: What have you tried so far? what error are you getting?

Comment: i made an edit to show what I have done so far.

Comment: are you trying to host asp and aspx pages in the same WebApp in IIS?

Comment: @lostknight you need to show the exact code you're using, and the exact error message you're getting. Otherwise we're only guessing what's going on. There are several ways you could redirect to the new site and pass data over. Potentially this kind of thing is going to be fraught with difficulty - for instance how are you sharing the user/session info securely? There are some examples online including by MS. Especially since it involves a commercial transaction you need to be 100% sure there are no security holes. I would get an outside expert to pen-test it once you're ready.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly you basically want your site to go to another page after a form submit, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you just need to put your destination page address in your `action` parameter in the original page `<form>` tag.

```
<form action="./destination_page.aspx">
    <!-- page content -->
</form>
```